# Encrypting files within a container on a virtual linux system without kernel modules

Tags: linux, virtualization, encryption, truecrypt

I have a virtualized linux system (vserver) that gives me all root privileges except manipulation of kernel modules. Now I wish to have a solution similar to TrueCrypt where I can create an encrypted container that I can mount as a drive. Unfortunately TrueCrypt requires me to load kernel modules which I cannot do (also FUSE is not an option).

Which alternatives do I have to encrypt a container on a system with some standard kernel modules and no means to dynamically load any more?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions need kernel modules or present kernel configuration parameters. So you need to find out if your kernel has the code included.

Then there are at least two good solutions like [dm-crypt](http://www.saout.de/misc/dm-crypt/) and [eCryptfs](https://launchpad.net/ecryptfs). Both encrypt whole file systems but in combination with a loop device you can have the file-system in a container.

Comment: So my initial fear was right :-(
I was kind of hoping that there was some clever solution that could circumvent using anything kernel related (even though my understanding of encryption containers made me think otherwise).
Thanks!